# ng-sortable for node js

Tags: node.js, express, ng-sortable

I want to make something like trello. I found a good plugin in http://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/kanban. Unfortunately, it was created for angularjs. Meanwhile, my existing web is created in nodejs/express. is there anybody how ti implement it in node/express? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to built this in express template engine like jade or ejs?
Why dont you integrate angularjs with your node/express?

Comment: yes, because my existing website is built in pug and I need to put a lot of effort if I have to change to angularjs

Comment: What if you dont have to change your whole website? Just point the specific route to load angularjs for Kanban board and get the data using api's because i think in pug it will be difficult to built a good looking kanban board